# Code doesn't enter in while loop even when condition is satisfied

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, multiprocessing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

I have a strange problem related to a while loop. I have a function which is called at the end of the parent of a process (`print_file()`) and it doesn't accept a true condition to go ahead. This is my simple multiprocess code as you can see below.

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* basic I/O routines.   */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>    /* define fork(), etc.   */
#include <sys/types.h> /* define pid_t, etc.    */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* define wait(), etc.   */
#include <signal.h>    /* define signal(), etc. */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_file(char* [], char* []);
void child_process(int,int);
void parent_process();
int counter=0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    counter = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i,k;
    pid_t child_pid;
    int child_status;
    char* array[counter];
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int temp;

    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
        temp = rand()%4;
        child_pid = fork();

        switch(child_pid) {
            case -1:
                printf("Error occured with fork()\n");
                exit(1);
            case 0: 
                child_process(i,temp); /* Child Process */
                exit(0);
        }
    }

    wait(&child_status);
    parent_process();
    execl("/usr/bin/killall","killall","tail",(char *) 0);
    return 0;
}

void child_process(int i,int temp){

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("sample.txt","a+");
    if( temp==0 ) {
        fprintf(fptr,"A %d\n",i);
    }
    else if( temp==1 ) {
        fprintf(fptr,"C %d\n",i);
    }
    else if( temp==2 ) {
        fprintf(fptr,"G %d\n",i);
    }
    else if( temp==3 ) {
        fprintf(fptr,"T %d\n",i);
    }
    fflush(fptr);
    sleep(1);
    fclose(fptr);
}

void parent_process(void){

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    char* str = (char*)malloc(1);
    int temp,i,k;
    char* array_opst[counter];
    char* array[counter];

    i=0;
    while(!feof(fptr)){

        fscanf(fptr,"%s%d",str,&temp);
        if(feof(fptr))
            break;

        if(strcmp(str,"A")==0){
            array[temp]="A";
            array_opst[temp]="T";
            printf("Array[%d] = %s\n",temp,array[temp]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(str,"C")==0){
            array[temp]="C";
            array_opst[temp]="G";
            printf("Array[%d] = %s\n",temp,array[temp]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(str,"G")==0){
            array[temp]="G";
            array_opst[temp]="C";
            printf("Array[%d] = %s\n",temp,array[temp]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(str,"T")==0){
            array[temp]="T";
            array_opst[temp]="A";
            printf("Array[%d] = %s\n",temp,array[temp]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    free(str);
    print_file(array,array_opst);
}

void print_file(char* array[counter], char* array_opst[counter]) {

    int j=0,i=1;

    while(j<counter){
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
        j++;
        if(i==10){
            i=0;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

In the `print_file` function it never enters into the while loop even when the condition is satisfied. But whenever I put a printf on the first line of the `print_file` function to check if it does succesfully enter it prints. (Be carefull that `counter` is a global variable). What causes this problem?

Comment: Did you log `counter`? It's probably `0`.

Comment: did you enter a break point and see what the actual values are for counter?

Comment: @DrummerB yes i logged counter and it prints the true value in calling function

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze wow thats why it was printing the duplicate of last line :)). thanks for suggestion

Comment: @quartaela, this also why you should check return values. :)

Comment: @hmjd or read the documentation with attention to details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output from the loop is not appearing due to `stdout` being buffered (the `printf()` statement inside the loop contains no `\n` and `stdout` is not explicitly `fflush()`d) and the call to `execl()` in `main()`, which replaces the current process image and `stdout` buffer is not flushed as usual on a normal program exit. Add a new-line character to the `printf()` or explicitly call `fflush(stdout);` after the loop.

---

There is a buffer overrun, causing undefined behaviour:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(1);
```

allocates 1 byte, `str` is then used thus:

```
fscanf(fptr,"%s%d",str,&temp);
```

`fscanf()` adds a null terminator overruning the end of `str` even if only one `char` is read. I can't see a reason for dynamically allocating this or even when it needs to be an array as the format of the lines seems to be a single `char` followed by an `int`:

```
fprintf(fptr,"A %d\n",i);
```

To fix this problem, just use a `char` and the format specifier `%c` instead:

```
char ch;

if (2 == fscanf(fptr, "%c%d", &ch, &temp))
{
}
```

Always check return values (`fopen()`, `fprintf()`, `fscanf()` etc).

Comment: i was facing with `segmentation fault error` before i used malloc thats why i allocate. on the other hand, why we check exactly `2` with the return value of fscanf _?

Comment: @quartaela, `fscanf()` returns the number of assignments made. As the call of `fscanf()` is attempting to assign a value to `ch` and `temp` the return value will be 2 if successful.

Comment: yeah i this way works too and more efficient i guess. on the other hand, it still couldnt enter in the while loop so that was not the reason of undefined behaviour _?

Comment: @quartaela, did you change all code that used `str`? Like `strcmp()` for example? (Just checking).

Comment: yeah i check characters like `if(str=='A')`

Comment: @quartaela, are you 100% certain that the value read into `temp` results in `temp >= 0 && temp < counter` as `temp` is used as an index into arrays with `counter` number of elements.

Comment: if we are talking about last function `void print_file(char* array[counter], char* array_opst[counter])` yeah i am absolutely sure and checked the `counter` value (which is global) and as you can see i assigned `j=0`. so it is impossible to fail the condition _?

Comment: @quartaela, I am referring to `parent_process()` function.

Comment: no i havent any problems about `parent_function()` the problem is in `print_file` function. and it never enters in the while loop.

Comment: @quartaela, the `printf()` inside the loop may not be appearing due to `stdout` buffering. As you `execlp()` the `stdout` will not (I _think_) get flushed. Add a `\n` to `printf()` within the loop or `fflush(stdout);` after the loop.

Comment: finally it worked!! i spent hours to realize this issue. thanks thanks thanksss :)